# ¿Cambiar la indentación por defecto en Angular CLI?

Tags: angular

Al generar un nuevo componente, mediante *Angular CLI*, la indentación, en `xxx.component.ts`, es de dos espacios. ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la indentación a 4 espacios?

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos cosas importantes en lo que se refiere a la creación de sangrías (indentation):

1) Las reglas de validación para saber si tus archivos están escritos de manera "correcta", esta validación en Angular se hace con **TSLint** y en particular en **TSLint** puedes usar una configuración como esta para lograr tener 4 espacios:

```
"indent": [true, "spaces", 4]
```

Como se explica en este enlace: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/indent/

En Angular estas reglas se configuran en el archivo **tslint.json**.

2) Ahora bien, la otra cuestión es la del **formato de tus archivos** que dependiendo tu editor de código se configura en diferentes lugares, por ejemplo para **WebStorm**, eso se puede cambiar en "Preferencias > Editor > Code Style > TypeScript > Tabs and Indents", como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: WebStorm cambiar configuración a 4 espacios]

Comment: Hola Alex. Estoy usando *Visual Studio Code*. Tengo configurada la indentación a 4 espacios. El problema lo tengo cuando genero componentes, servicios, etc. directamente que me aparece una indentación de 2, supongo que será alguna configuración de Angular CLI.